# Prepend not working on JSON data

Tags: jquery, jsonp, prepend, json

I'm trying to return some data from twitter's JSONP results. I'm then trying to customize the response and prepend my own "ID" parameters so I can use it as a key in a key/value pair when I transform it back into JSON. I'm kind of confused as to why the jQuery prepend function is not working for this case.

here is a short bit of code i'm working with

```
$.getJSON('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?user_name=twitterapi&callback=?', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i) {
        $(data[i].id_str).prepend("id:"); //foobar, doesn't prepend anything
    });
```

PS. I know this isn't the formatted result I ultimately want but the question is about prepending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does that json result look like?
Aren't you trying just to do some string concatenation? Maybe this helps:

```
"id:"+data[i].id_str;
```

Comment: yep, just did this before i checked the page again. This helped solve the issue I was having.

Answer (score 0):

`data[i].id_str` does this string contain `"#"`. If not then you need to set append `"#"` to it in order to find the element.

Comment: i.e. $("#" + data[i].id_str).prepend("id:");

Comment: no, not really. The answer I marked was actually the real problem. I didn't really have to do prepend afterall.